# Cakephp Self referring Model Not working

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a table

```
Medias:
    ID,
    PARENT_ID
    PATH
    TITLE

Items:
    ID
    medias
    Title
    description
```

Models

```
class ImageGallery extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'ImageGallery';
    public $useTable = "medias";

    var $belongsTo = array( 
        'Parent' => 
        array('className' => 'ImageGallery', 
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
            'dependent' => false, 
        ), 
    );

    var $hasMany = array( 
        'Children' => 
        array('className' => 'ImageGallery', 
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        ), 
    ); 
}


class Item extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = "items";
    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),

    );

    public $belongsTo = array(

        'Gallery'   => array(
            'className' => 'ImageGallery', 
            'foreignKey'    =>  'medias'),
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'ItemMeta'  => array( 'className' => 'ItemMeta'),
    );
}
```

The media table contains gallery information.  Images are stored in parent_id relation.

When I request `Item->find('all');` I am getting only one entry from Media table, but I want to get all its children too. :(

I can get its children by using `$this->ImageGallery->findById(10);`, but I want to get them with the Item Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the containable behavior to specify which associated models you want the query to get.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

```
$this->Item->find('all', array('contain' => array('ImageGallery' => array('Children'))));
```

If you're looking to go deeper than just the child level, like if you want to get the rest of the tree, then you'll need to either write something to recursively fetch the children, the children's children, etc., or perhaps you can alter your code and models to make use of CakePHP's Tree Behavior.  See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html and http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/02/17/cakephp-and-tree-structures/